# Access Query: the specified expression is not included

Tags: sql, ms-access

I need to update `Table1.Budget` with `sum(Employee.[Monthly budget])` considering only employees that have the date of recruitment after `Table1.Date`.

I am trying to use this query:

```
UPDATE Table1 SET Budget = (Sum(Employee.[Monthly budget])) WHERE Table1.Date > Employee.[Date of recruitment];
```

but I get this error:

[image]

[image]

[image]

**EDIT**

I am using this code:

```
UPDATE Table1
    SET Budget = (SELECT Sum(Employee.[Monthly budget]) FROM Employee WHERE Table1.Date > Employee.[Date of recruitment]);
```

but I get the error message `Operation must use an updatable query`.

Answer (score 1):

I think you want a subquery, perhaps:

```
UPDATE Table1
    SET Budget = (SELECT Sum(Employee.[Monthly budget]) FROM Employee WHERE Table1.Date > Employee.[Date of recruitment]);
```

Comment: thanks but it says that there is a syntax error (missing operator) in `(Sum(Employee.[Monthly budget])) FROM Employee WHERE Table1.Date > Employee.[Date of recruitment])`

Comment: @Stefano  . . . A subquery should have `SELECT` (as it now does).

Comment: sorry again but if I put SELECT, I get "Operation must use an updateable query"

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any SELECT FROM Employee:

```
UPDATE Table1 
SET Budget = 
SELECT Sum(Employee.[Monthly budget]) 
FROM Employee 
WHERE Table1.[Date] > Employee.[Date of recruitment];
```

Comment: thank but I get "Operation must use an updateable query" :(

Comment: Date is a reserved word in Access.Needs to be put between square brackets. Adapted my code. Avoid using reserved words.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the 'Operation must use an updateable query' issue, just replace your subquery with a `DSUM()`.
It's probably slower, but should do the work.

```
UPDATE Table1 
SET Budget = DSUM("Monthly Budget", "Employees", "[Date of recruitement] < " & [Date])
```

(quickly written, but you get the idea)

By the way using Date as a field name is a VERY bad idea !!!